# Proving that a sequence converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove or disprove that there is a sequence $n_k$ of positive integers (that is not constant) such that both $\cos(2n_k!)$ and $\sin(2n_k!)$ converge.

I think that the series diverges but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: I edited your post. Please verify that this is what you meant.

Comment: Does $n_k = 1$ for all $k$ count?

Comment: A constant sequence makes both converge...

Comment: Oh, true. But what if the sequence isn't constant?

Comment: Presumably you mean a strictly increasing sequence. It would be enough to show there is one for sine.

Comment: Here's an idea which doesn't quite work, but maybe somebody else can work out the snag.  Consider the sequence {3, 3100, 314000, 31410000, 3141500000,...} where we use the use the decimal digits of the expansion of pi and scale up by a power of 10. The idea is to take the factorial of these guys as approximations to k*pi so the value will be closer to an integral multiple of pi as the sequence progresses.  The snag is that I can't show that the remainder gets actually smaller, but maybe a similar sequence might do the job, any ideas ?

Comment: Show that $\{(\cos(n!), \sin(n!)) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not finite ($\pi$ is not rational).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the subset of the square $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ consisting of coordinate pairs $(\cos(2n!), \sin(2n!))$. The square is a compact region, and we have an infinite number of coordinate pairs. Thus there is at least one accumulation point. [This is one of the very many characterizations of compactness]. Any such limit point is a possible limit, and any infinite subset of the sequence of integers leading to that accumulation point will yield a choice of the $n_k$.

This is completely nonconstructive. I do not know how many accumulation points there are, nor what any of the accumulation points are. But it is nonetheless easy to show that there exists a choice of $n_k$ that make both sequences converge. $\diamondsuit$

Comment: But then why using the factorial? Why not simply $\cos(2n)$ and $\sin(2n)$, i.e. $n_k=k$?